# html5 video player progress bar click funcion

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

Is it possible to listen on html 5 video player default progress bar click using j query having specific video tag id?
video tag is like

```
<video width="250" height="150" id="videoplayer" controls="" autoplay="" src="blob:https%3A//fiddle.jshell.net/91a12a0d-f082-4fbd-a70c-7fa94563690c"></video>
```

can i get click event of id="videoplayer" on progress bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the set of events possible to track are listed at the link mentioned:- 
Link:- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Example:- https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

I hope this would help you.

Thanks and Regards
Kautuk Sahni

Answer (score 1):

Try the "seeking" event. It will be called if you click on the progress bar.

```
let videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
videoPlayer.addEventListener("seeking", function(){
  console.log('seeking', videoPlayer.currentTime)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add eventlistener to video player by this way:

```
document.getElementById('videoplayer').addEventListener("click", function(){
    //the code you want to do in click event
});
```

And on the other hand you can handle it by using your custom video player like this:

```
<div id="video-controls" class="controls" data-state="hidden">
   <button id="playpause" type="button" data-state="play">Play/Pause</button>
   <button id="stop" type="button" data-state="stop">Stop</button>
   <div class="progress">
      <progress id="progress" value="0" min="0">
         <span id="progress-bar"></span>
      </progress>
   </div>
   <button id="mute" type="button" data-state="mute">Mute/Unmute</button>
   <button id="volinc" type="button" data-state="volup">Vol+</button>
   <button id="voldec" type="button" data-state="voldown">Vol-</button>
   <button id="fs" type="button" data-state="go-fullscreen">Fullscreen</button>
</div>
```

And then, you can listen your progress bar with using it's id value.

Answer (score 0):

use `<progress>` element is with an HTML5 video

```
<progress id='p'></progress>
```